# compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors

Tags: c++, poo, clase, headers

Encontré en internet un código de la Universidad de Illinois que me pareció muy interesante (trata sobre la modificación de una fotografía PNG por medio del cálculo y modificación de su matriz) , pero al ejecutarlo, se encuentra un error el cual no sé cómo corregirlo. El error al ejecutarlo es el siguiente:

```
 make
g++  -std=c++14   -g -O0 -pedantic -Wall -Wfatal-errors -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -MMD -MP -msse2 -c main.cpp -o .objs/main.o
In file included from ImageTransform.h:3:0,
                from main.cpp:9:
uiuc/PNG.h:89:5: error: ‘HSLAPixel’ does not name a type
    HSLAPixel & getPixel(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) const;
    ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
uiuc/make/uiuc.mk:55: recipe for target '.objs/main.o' failed
make: *** [.objs/main.o] Error 1
exit status 2

```

Para ver el código completo está subido a Replit: https://repl.it/repls/InsubstantialHurtfulBoolean

Al parecer sólo tiene un error, y se encuentra en la carpeta "uiuc" en el file PNG.h

Comment: El error es claro y sencillo: `'HSLAPixel' does not name a type`: `El nombre 'HSLAPixel' no identifica ningún tipo conocido en este punto`. Tiene toda la pinta de que estás mezclando versiones incompatibles de código; seguramente, la librería PNG que estás usando es, o demasiado antigua, o demasiado moderna.

Comment: Ya lo vi mejor. Tanto la cabecera como el cuerpo de la clase HSLAPixel no están definidos (es decir, no hay código) por lo cual ocasiona dicho error. Igualmente gracias.